# Sonata Admin Bundle custom query for list to use existing Repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I have my admin class creating a custom list using createQuery method

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query->andWhere(
        ....
    );
    ....
    return $query;
}
```

It all works just fine, but since I have repository with this query already defined and tests already written for that repository I was wondering if it was possible to utilize doctrine repository method instead of this?

Thanks

Comment: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list

Answer (score 17):

Of course you can, as far as you return a Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery instance :

```
   /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $repository = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager($this->getClass())->getRepository($this->getClass());
        $query = new ProxyQuery($repository->createMyCustomQueryBuilder());

        foreach ($this->extensions as $extension) {
            $extension->configureQuery($this, $query, $context);
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: here is more about it: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list

Comment: Link is dead: new link https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/3.x/reference/action_list/#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list